# How to install Pervasive Direct Access components in Delphi-XE7

Tags: delphi-xe7, pervasive

I have been trying for two days to install Pervasive PDAC components. I do everything according to Actian instructions. After selecting the required .bpl files, I keep on getting a message that the specified module could not be found. I have tried every thing that I can think about. Added the relevant folder to the library path. Started Delphi as administrator but nothing helps. The following is the error I am getting. I have V10 installed but can only find V11-PDAC

[image]

Comment: Would you please give the EXACT error message and when you get it (IDE startup, compiling, running,...) Do not answer in comment, edit your post to add that information.

Comment: What exact BPL are you installing?  What version of the PDAC SDK are you installing?  What version of the Pervasive / Actian engine are you using? What's the actual error?    Add all of that information to your post.

Comment: One more thing, what instructions are you following?

Comment: I have edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the same error using Delphi 10.3.  Once I added the location of the PDAC lib directory for the version of Delphi to my System Path, I was able to install the PDAC components and use them in a VCL application.  I had tried adding the location to both the `Library Path` and `Browsing Path` and was able to install the package but got an error when trying to create a new VCL application.

As an alternative, I added the location of the extracted PDAC files (`...\PDAC\DelphiXXX\x86\Lib`) to the `Library Path` and `Browsing Path`.  I then copied the BPL files for the compiler version (in my case Delphi 10.3) from the lib path to where my Pervasive v11 was installed (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Pervasive Software\PSQL\bin`) and I was able to install the package, selecting the "D" BPL from the Pervasive install directory, not the LIB directory.  Once installed, I was able to create a VCL application and access the data on a remote server using a `TPvSession` and `TPvTable` component.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works 100%. I just drop a pvTable on the form without a session. Change the tables DatabaseName to the full path where the Pervasive data is stored.

Comment: Don't forget, you'll need the PvSession (or PvSqlSession with PvQuery) to access remote databases.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advise. I am most probably at 68 one of the oldest developer around. My first coding was done in COBAL on a NCR mainframe and the source code was still stored on punch cards. If it was not for the fantastic I support and advise I receive from you and the other from the Stack Overflow team I would most probably be sitting on my patio and dying of boredom and living from cold water and bread. Thanks again to a fantastic team sharing their knowledge. You guys are great